# Non-Repetition constraint in the non-key attributes for each key attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to establish a table in which the the non-key attributes for each value in key attributes are not repeated. for example , the following table show the locations of several companies in several cities, and the needed constraint states that each company should have at most one branch for each city.

| Company_name | city |
| --- | --- |
| Amazon | London |
| Amazon | Berlin |
| Microsoft | London |
| Microsoft | Berlin |

how to establish a such constraint in which we make sure that Amazon or Microsoft have two branches in Berlin?

Using UNIQUE Constraint alone is not enough ,as it makes the city name will not be repeated two times to present the locations of several company, so something more is needed, any suggestion?

Comment: Make the unique constraint on the combination of both columns?

Comment: in this case the company name will be presented only one time, which is not valid for presenting two locations

Comment: A unique index on the two columns will constrain uniqueness for the combination, not the individual columns. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_some_name ON tbl (company_name, city);`

Comment: thanks everyone for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a *composite unique constraint* including both `Company_name` and `city`  columns: that way what's unique is the couple of them.

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT company_name_city UNIQUE (company_name, city);
```

Comment: thanks everyone for answering my question